# How can i find the walls boundaries and compare them to the 4 directions from the player to find what directions the player can move to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a grid of cubes.
The grid size in this case is 10x10
Each cube size is 1x1
Each wall is a child under walls and on each wall there is the wall cubes as childs.

[image: walls]

The Walls parent GameObject position is at X = 29.4 Y = 0.5 Z = 10.9
And each wall position is at 0,0,0

After creating the grid i'm finding the walls then i'm getting the player current position and then i'm getting each direction from the player + 1.5f distance.

Next i want to find what directions the player can move to. forward,left,right,backward since the player is spawn each time running the game on once of the walls edge then one direction or two directions can't be move to.

The problem is how to find the direction/s that can't be moved to and thos that can ?

```
private void Directions()
    {
        GameObject walls = GameObject.Find("Walls");
        Vector3 playerPosition = player.position;

        Vector3 rightOnePointFive = player.localPosition + player.right * 1.5f;
        Vector3 leftOnePointFive = player.localPosition - player.right * 1.5f;
        Vector3 forwardOnePointFive = player.localPosition + player.forward * 1.5f;
        Vector3 backOnePointFive = player.localPosition - player.forward * 1.5f;
    }
```

This is how i'm creating the grid and the walls:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public GameObject[] allBlocks;

    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];

    void Start()
    {
        wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
        wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
        wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
        wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void AutoGenerateGrid()
    {
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        for (int i = 0; i < allBlocks.Length; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(allBlocks[i]);
        }

        var end = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("End");
        DestroyImmediate(end);

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.name = "Block";
                block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);

                if (x == 0)//TOP
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[0].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "TopWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == 0)//LEFT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[1].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "LeftWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == gridHeight - 1)//RIGHT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[2].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "RightWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }

                else if (x == gridWidth - 1)//BOTTOM
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[3].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "BottomWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I tried this method:

```
private GridGenerator gridgenerator;

public void FindDirection()
{
    gridgenerator = GetComponent<GridGenerator>();
    GenerateStartEnd();
    Directions();
}

private void Directions()
{
    Vector3 playerPosition;
    playerPosition = player.localPosition;

    if (playerPosition.x > 0)
    {
        // can go left
        possibleDirections[0] = "Can go left";
    }

    if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth)
    {
        // can go right
        possibleDirections[1] = "Can go right";
    }

    if (playerPosition.z > 0)
    {
        // can go forward
        possibleDirections[2] = "Can go forward";
    }

    if (playerPosition.z + 1 < gridgenerator.gridHeight)
    {
        // can go backward
        possibleDirections[3] = "Can go backward";
    }
}
```

But when running the game:

[image: Directions]

The only direction i can't go is left but it's saying in the inspector i can go left. and can go forward but can't go backward and right.

I messed it all

In this case the gridWidth and gridHeight both 10 but i t can be any size like 23x5 or 9x7 or 12x12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way would be to use a 2 dimensional array.

With this it would be very easy to check where your player can go by saving the current player position. This means, that if your player is at position [0,5], he could not move to the left side.

additionally you could also auto generate the field and easily adjust its size.

Edit:
However if you really want to keep your current solution, you could loop through every wall and check if the x position is smaller than your current player position, when you want to move left. Same thing with the other directions.

Edit2:
[image]

look at this beautiful drawn picture for a better example.

if you have a two dimensional array, you can store the current player position and then do the following code.

Ok so maybe I wasn't clear enough, but it was already 4am and I was a little bit tired. What you have to do is to store the current playerPosition, which can only be integers. So the possibilities would be for example: [0,0], [3,0], [2,3]. Whenever you move your player to the left you have to update his position on the grid, for example when you go left playerPosition.X--;

```
Vector2 playerPos = new Vector(0, 3);
int maxWidthOfGrid = 5;


private void Directions()
{
    if(playerPos.X > 0) {
        //player can go left
    }
    if(playerPos.X+1 < maxWidthOfGrid) {
        //player can go right
    }

}
```

I haven't tested the code, so maybe you have to modify it a little.

same goes for the bottom and top directions.

Comment: I added to my question the code of how i'm creating the grid and the walls. The code before is in another script that's why i did GameObject walls = GameObject.Find("Walls"); If you can show me example how to do it with the easiest way ? Why at 5,0 the player can't move left ?

Comment: What you want to do is add an abstraction layer to simplify your logic. Instead of dealing with raw position, use this two a 2 dimensional array to define where your objects are in relative positions, the array element should be a rich object (or link to one) that can give you the raw position and other properties that you need for rendering once your logical state has been computed.

Comment: Sebastian i tried but i'm getting wrong possible directions. I updated my question with what i tried.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough, but it was already 4am so I was a little tired. However I updated my solution.

Comment: @SebastianKilb No it's ok. It's working fine when the grid is 10x10 for example but when i add spaces between the cubes for example block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f); then sometimes it's showing wrong results. For example it's showing it can't go forward but it can.  Maybe i need to update the gridWidth and gridHeight when adding spaces ?

Comment: If you do it like this you have to include the spacing. So if your grid is 10x10 the width would be 10 * (cube width + spacing). But using a second array as Chris also mentioned would be cleaner.

Comment: @SebastianKilb Yes i saw Chris comment before but i didn't understand how to do it. I'm sure there is a better way to make it cleaner. Maybe you can give me a lead or show me how to do it using Chris idea ?